# Awaitatility, polling until condition is met

Tags: java, awaitility

i'm trying to use awaitatility for some testing purposes.

This piece of code im trying to use is giving me problems:

```
    await()
            .atLeast(Duration.ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS)
            .atMost(Duration.FIVE_SECONDS)
            .with()
            .pollInterval(Duration.ONE_HUNDRED_MILLISECONDS)
            .until(result.contains("banana"));
```

Result is a string variable in which i save some remote system output earlier in the code.
But when i try to use it like this, i get the following error :

> "until (java.util.concurrent.Callable) in
>   ConditionFactory cannot be applied to (boolean)"

What is the proper way to use the library? I want too see if certain data/text string has managed to get retrieved from my remote system before i do a bunch of asserts on the data fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`until` needs to take a **function** that returns a boolean (i.e. a `Callable<Boolean>`), not just a boolean.

`result.contains("banana")` is a method call that returns a boolean. That means that `.until(result.contains("banana"))` is evaluated to `.until(false)` or `.until(true)`

Comment: Thanks!

Changed this now to this:

                .until(new Callable<Boolean>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call() throws Exception
                    {
                        return (result).contains("banana");
                    }
                });

And it seems to work fine :)

Comment: @CobraKai Glad to hear.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give until a callable. ie

```
await().until(() -> result.contains("banana"));
```